# encoding japanese character in tomcat and in Java Deskop Produce Different result

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding

i have a question, why java desktop and webapps produce different result?

for example i have to encode this String 秋田県秋田市山手台２

i have split that String into int array to be coded as Char

the result is

```
31179
30000
30476
31179
30000
24066
23665
25163
21488
65298
```

and i encode it with WebApp in tomcat (no framework) with this QUery String ?x=秋田県秋田市山手台２

the code is

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    int[] r = {31179,
        30000,
        30476,
        31179,
        30000,
        24066,
        23665,
        25163,
        21488,
        65298};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        int j = r[i];
        sb.append((char) j);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

the result is ????????

but when i decode it with Java Desktop with this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    int[] r = {31179,
        30000,
        30476,
        31179,
        30000,
        24066,
        23665,
        25163,
        21488,
        65298};
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        int j = r[i];
        sb.append((char)j);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

the result is 秋田県秋田市山手台２

why that can be different ? is that something wrong? i have tried with URLEncode utf-8
and it did same

i have search it on google that i have to change the Server.xml in conf directory the XML is here

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
    <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
         define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
         Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
     -->
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
      -->
      <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
          <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-      howto.html -->
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
      <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

      <!-- Global JNDI resources
           Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
      -->
      <GlobalNamingResources>
        <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
             UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
        -->
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                  description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                  pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
      </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    **<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />**
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

          </Host>
        </Engine>
      </Service>
    </Server>
```

it still produce the same result , any solution for this??

Comment: It's probably different default character sets.  You can get the default charset by using `java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset()`

Comment: oh yes you are right that's different now, but what Encoding should i use? if i use UTF-8  result is ç§‹ç”°çœŒç§‹ç”°å¸‚å±±æ‰‹å�°ï¼’ if i use UTF 16 all result from tomcat produce a strange symbol,

Comment: Your character codes (31179, 30000, etc...) are encoded from characters in a specific character set (probably not utf-8 or utf-16).  I've had to deal with japanese stuff before and in my experience the rule that has served me is "Keep everything utf-8 and the world is happy.  Stray from that even a little, and descend into misery forever."  Practically, you could keep the text in a utf-8 encoded properties file or as characters in the (utf-8 encoded) java source file.  Be sure the file is saved as utf-8 and the application is configured to run as utf-8 and you should be good.

Comment: @Taylor ah yes u R right , i am using windows the default encoding is windows-blablabla so that's why i got strange chars , i will keep in mind that "Keep everything utf-8 and the world is happy. Stray from that even a little, and descend into misery forever."  it solved now , when i upload it in linux , everything looks fine (standard encoding is UTF-8 in linux) thank u :)

Comment: I have edited my answer now it will work, check it out, if it work for you then accept it, Thanks